# ALM - Track application deployment

Tags: deployment, tfs, tfs-2015

We are using TFS 2015 for a quite of time. We have a lots of projects that running on the TFS solution. We use the Release Managements tools built-in to make the deployment and tracking more simple. But in our business context, we must deploy many different project in many different server (OnPremise, Azure, third party hosting). Some project use dependencies with other project.

The major problem we have actually is that we cannot track effectively where our different applications is deployed and wich have dependencies with other.
When is time to make maintenance on server or service, we have a hard time to detect all the dependencies and all projects that going to be affected.

We can check in every TFS project, on the Release Managements and edit every environments config, but this is not a solution as the number of projects grown.

What is the best strategy or guideline ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid  using the [Release Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/release-management-vs.aspx)  is the best choice for your situation. Even though you will met some performance or management limitation with the number of projects grown.

> **Release management retain full traceability** (permanent audit trails)
>
> - Monitor the current status of the releases and deployments to all the    environments.
> - Track the status of recent deployments in each of the environments.
> - Retain detailed audit history of all the activities performed on a    release.
> - See the commits and work items that are associated with each release.

And since you are using it to make the deployment, is it not the best choice. You have said your team must deploy many different project in many different server (OnPremise, Azure, third party hosting). As you might imagine, which third-party tool or system will handle the such a complex cross-platform environment. And this tool should also tracking the source code, the deployment result through Release Management...

Comment: Thanks for reply :)

Comment: I made research over internet and in some ebook for ALM/DevOps concept, it seem to have no solution or guideline for our problem. 
I cannot imagine that we are the only company that must manage many projects from the developpment stage to the deployment and managing. There must be a solution or something that it can help us to release the burden of managing. If i found someting, i will update this post.

Comment: Custom solution is the way to go.